# Amazon SP-API Access token is missing error

Tags: php, amazon-selling-partner-api

I get the following result from an SP-API call using CURL within PHP. It is a private app created in Seller Central, and all permissions have been granted. We are just trying to retrieve our data.

```
Array (
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => Unauthorized
                    [message] => Access to requested resource is denied.
                    [details] => Access token is missing in the request header.
                )

        )

)
```

An access token is retrieved with a refresh token and included; here is the code. amazonApiUrl is https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken
        );

        $curl = curl_init($this->amazonApiUrl."/catalog/2022-04-01/items?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER");

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'XXXXXXXXX-app/v1');

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

The access token exists and has been retrieved from https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token#. What can be wrong? I was expecting our products list but getting the above error.

Comment: The error message says that the access token is missing from the request, so there is something wrong with your headers. Have you looked at [this page](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/amazon-shipping/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api)? Another option is to use a pre-built API library - try searching for "amazon selling partner api for PHP" and you will see that there are several libraries available, none of which I have tested.